# How to build and package lambda layers containing all the dependencies in a java maven project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin, aws-lambda-layers

I want to be able to build and package lambda layers along with the lambda functions in the same maven multi-module project. How can I do that?

I am able to successfully do it by creating a separate maven project for all the dependencies and then use it as a dependency in the other maven multi-module project containing the lambda functions. I want to avoid the creation and maintenance of separate projects just for lambda layers.